# Booking for WooCommerce does not work with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xcode, blogs, woocommerce-bookings

After installing "Booking for Woocommerce" my Wordpress Blog crashes.When trying to open any post of my blog, this message pops up and dthe blog side is unavailable:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on bool in /var/www/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-content/plugins/mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce/public/class-mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce-public.php:78 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Mwb_Bookings_For_Woocommerce_Public->mbfw_public_enqueue_scripts('') #1 /var/www//webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /var/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /var/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2180): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #4 /var/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): wp_enqueue_scripts('') #5 /var/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 /var/www/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-includes/pl in /var/www/webXXXXX/html/newXdomain/wp-content/plugins/mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce/public/class-mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce-public.php on line 78

I need help - step by step - to solve this

Tried a code that was given yetserday on this forum. but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

go to the directory where your website code lives.

then take a look at this file, line 78

```
/wp-content/plugins/mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce/public/class-mwb-bookings-for-woocommerce-public.php:78
```

for the place where it calls $variableName->get_type()

My guess is, that $variableName (whatever it is) is not set, so false.
Tracing the error like this should give you an idea how to fix it.

It looks like this plugin has no proper validation for these cases. In this case, contact the author.

Comment: No idea what variable that could be. The author is swing and I assumed, it is their forum here ?

Answer (score 0):

please your are plugin update in check it.